# Как программно удалить Textview

Tags: java, android, textview

Всем привет!
В приложении при нажатии кнопки появляется Textview с фоном. При нажатии кнопки повторно, Textview "пропадает". 
Проблема в том, что остальные кнопки, которое оно закрывало, становятся невозможно нажать. То есть Textview не пропадает совсем, а просто становится прозрачным.
Как полностью его убрать?

```
public
        void onClick(View s) {
            InfoText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
            int status = (Integer) s.getTag();
            if (status == 2) {
                InfoText.setText(R.string.Infotext);
                InfoText.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                s.setTag(1);
            }else {

                InfoText.setText(null);
                InfoText.setBackgroundResource(null);
                s.setTag(2);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Главный вопрос, а нужно ли удалять?
По сути необходимо, чтобы нажатие передовалось ниже.
Если сделать textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE), оно не будет обрабатывать нажатия, и видимо тоже

Comment: Да, очень простое и действенное решение, спасибо)
пришлось еще, правда, добавить  InfoText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); в другой вариант действия кнопки

Answer (score 0):

Существует обратный метод для удаления вида - removeView(), а также метод removeAllViews(), удаляющий все дочерние элементы родителя. Рассмотрим следующий пример. Создадим разметку, где компонент LinearLayout с идентификатором master будет родителем для будущих элементов, которые мы будем добавлять или удалять:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/enlayer1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enable Layer 1" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/enlayer2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enable Layer 2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/master"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Создадим пару дополнительных макетов, которые будет дочерними элементами для FrameLayout. Мы будем управлять ими программно.

**layer1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Layer 1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="EditText" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**layer2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Layer 2" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox A" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox B" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox C" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Напишем код, который будет добавлять или удалять компоновки через флажки.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout mainLayer;
    View layer1, layer2;
    CheckBox enableLayer1, enableLayer2, enableLayer3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        enableLayer1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.enlayer1);
        enableLayer2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.enlayer2);

        mainLayer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.master);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        layer1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layer1, null);
        layer2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layer2, null);

        enableLayer1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(enableLayer1ChangeListener);
        enableLayer2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(enableLayer2ChangeListener);
    }

    CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener enableLayer1ChangeListener = new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                mainLayer.addView(layer1);
            } else {
                mainLayer.removeView(layer1);
            }
        }
    };

    CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener enableLayer2ChangeListener = new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                mainLayer.addView(layer2);
            } else {
                mainLayer.removeView(layer2);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

в вашем случае все будет почти так же, только удалять вы будете вам TextView.

[Ссылка](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/addview.php) на первоисточник. Надеюсь я вам помог в решении вашей проблемы. Удачи :)

Comment: Может и помогли, спасибо) но SDK отказывается воспринимать и addView и removeView как часть кода

Comment: а что пишет? типа неизвестные методы?

Comment: Ну да. То есть эти методы еще нужно дополнительно прописать?)

Comment: а вы сделали все так же как и в примере? просто если в первоисточнике есть эти методы, значит они прижились)) посмотрите может вы что-то не учли, эти методы я видел уже неоднократно и на других ресурсах, значит их создавать дополнительно не нужно

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, попробую